# Can't copy image to assets folder on real device flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, image, dart, assets

When I select an image from gallery on iPhone, i want to copy it into the assets/images folder and display it afterwards.
On Simulator everything works fine. But on real device I get the following error:

```
Runner[44762:20816132] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '../../assets/images/image_picker_39C262A3-37A8-4167-8A9A-809C05C6DA67-44762-000025ACD7154E4A.jpg', path = '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4691143F-EC0F-470D-B7EC-88A9BCF021F8/tmp/image_picker_39C262A3-37A8-4167-8A9A-809C05C6DA67-44762-000025ACD7154E4A.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _File.copy.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:328:9)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _ProductInputPageState.getFromGallery (package:outfitcreator/pages/product_input_page.dart:451:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I put the folder into the pubspec.yaml.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Do you have any suggestion how to encounter this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy files to your asset folder in runtime. After you pick the image you can save it to the temp dorectory or any other device folders like this

```dart
final Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String localPath = docDir.path;
File file = File('$localPath/${path.split('/').last}');
final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load(path);
final buffer = imageBytes.buffer;
await file.writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(imageBytes.offsetInBytes, imageBytes.lengthInBytes));
```